# Xcode - Tracking User Usage

Tags: ios, xcode, tracking

Is there a way to track when, and for how long, users spend on different screens of an app?

I have developed an app as part of my PhD research but need to record app usage when participants have access to the app - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase Console you can check your app Analytics and you can see a lot of analytics on there such as this below pic:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that - I’m I right in thinking you can just see the aggregate for each screen rather than seeing each individuals usage?

Comment: you can define an event per user or each custom parameter you want.
you can see all features in firebase analytics
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics#:~:text=Key%20capabilities,-Unlimited%20Reporting&text=Analytics%20provides%20unlimited%20reporting%20on%20up%20to%20500%20distinct%20events.&text=Custom%20audiences%20can%20be%20defined,new%20features%20or%20notification%20messages.